# ffmpeg downmix to 5.1+2.0 from 5.1

Tags: ffmpeg, stereo, 5.1

I need output of 5.1 + 2.0 (PCM, 6 mono tracks + 1 stereo track) from a 5.1 source. This means I need:
first 6 channels input --> ch1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (mono tracks)
+
first 6 channels --> ch7-8 (stereo track)

Have tried:

-ac 2 -af "pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.30*FL+0.30*BL|FR=FC+0.30*FR+0.30*BR"

but this obviously gives output 2 tracks (in one channel). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way is to use [`map_channel`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) and `pan` for the downmix:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex
                "[0]pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.30*FL+0.30*BL|FR=FC+0.30*FR+0.30*BR[st]"
       -map 0:v -c:v copy
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.0:0.1
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.1:0.2
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.2:0.3
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.3:0.4
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.4:0.5
       -map 0:a -map_channel 0.1.5:0.6
       -map "[st]" output.mov
```